# Updating or changing specific data in Treeview, Python 3.9

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, edit

I have made a script that catches the input from the user and converts it into various files (I know there is a direct way using only excel but I want a backup copy of this data just in case something happens with the excel version which anybody can open/change).
I have got to a point where when trying to edit the columns when the data is transfered to treeview, I cant specify what exactly needs to be changed and can't find any direct answers on the internet. Im pretty new at this so any help would be greatly appreciated and even more so if it is put into laymen's terms.

```
def tree_editable():


''' Create a toplevel window that can be edited and used to create an excel file using the Treeview widget'''
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import  BOTTOM, S, X, Y
from tkinter import ttk,Label, Menu
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview
fd = filedialog
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

window = Toplevel()
window.geometry('1000x800')
window.title('Client list table')
window.resizable(False, False)
frame1 = Frame(window)
frame1.pack()
my_tree = Treeview(frame1)

def file_open():
    filename = fd.askopenfilename(title= "Open a file", filetypes = [("Excel files", "*.xlsx"), ('CSV Files', '*.csv')])

    if filename:
        try:
            filename = r'{}'.format(filename)
            df = pd.read_excel(filename)
        except ValueError:
            error_label.config(text="File Didn't Work. Try again")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            error_label.config(text="File Not Found.")

    # Clear old tree view
    clear_tree()
    # Set new Treeview

    my_tree["column"] = list(df.columns)
    my_tree ["show"] = 'headings'

    # Loop through the column list for headers
    for column in my_tree["column"]:
        my_tree.heading(column, text=column)

    # Put data in treeview
    df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()

    for row in df_rows:
        my_tree.insert('', 'end', values = row)

    def change():
        selected = my_tree.focus()
        print (selected)
        values = my_tree.item(selected, 'values')
        

    def update():
        focused = my_tree.focus()
        x = input('Enter a Value you want to change')
        my_tree.item(focused, values=("", str(x)))
    
    my_tree.bind("<Double-Button>", lambda e: change())
    select = ttk.Button(frame1, text='Edit', command = change()).pack()
    

    update = Button(frame1, text='update', command= update).pack(pady=10)

    my_treeScroll = ttk.Scrollbar(frame1 )
    my_treeScroll.pack(side = RIGHT, fill=Y)
    

    my_treeScroll.configure(command=my_tree.yview)
    my_tree.configure(yscrollcommand=my_treeScroll.set)

    my_treeScroll_x = ttk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient='horizontal' )
    my_treeScroll_x.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill= X)
    

    my_treeScroll_x.configure(command=my_tree.xview)
    my_tree.configure(xscrollcommand=my_treeScroll_x.set)

    my_tree.pack()

def clear_tree():
    my_tree.delete(*my_tree.get_children())

error_label = tk.Label(text='')
error_label.pack
my_menu = Menu(window)
window.config(menu=my_menu)
file_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff= False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Spreadsheets", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=file_open)
```